# How to use date in x value for Object[] in chartjs dataset, I am getting an error: 'TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.'

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am currently trying to implement a Object[] instead of an Primitive[] for the data set in Chartjs. I'm using Angular in combination with Chart.js 3.6.0 and ng2-charts 3.0.0-rc.7

**line-chart.component.ts:**

```
import { ChartConfiguration, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
import * as moment from "moment";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-chart',
  templateUrl: './line-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.scss']
})
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit {
....

public lineChartData: ChartConfiguration['data'] = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [
          {x: '2021', y: 12}, > TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        ],
        label: 'FBSV',
      }
    ],
    // empty for for dynamic structuring.
    labels: []
  };

public lineChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: this.title,
        color: '#25167A',
        font: {
          size: 15,
          weight: 'bold'
        }
      },
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0.25 // creates smoother lines
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        display: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Year',
          color: '#25167A',
          font: {
            size: 15,
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        },
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'year'
        }
      },
      y: {
        display: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Score',
          color: '#25167A',
          font: {
            size: 15,
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        },
        max: 100,
        min: 0,
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  };

  public lineChartType: ChartType = 'line';

  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart?: BaseChartDirective;

....
```

The problem is that in the Chart.js 3.6.0 docs it states that you should be able to use non primative data values:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html

**line-chart.component.html:**

```
<canvas baseChart
              [data]="lineChartData"
              [options]="lineChartOptions"
              [type]="lineChartType">
      </canvas>
```

How can I fix this in order to be able to use dates in the x value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your own type to the `ChartConfiguration` interface as a second parameter like so:

```
const lineChartData: ChartConfiguration<"line", { x: string, y: number }[]> = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [
          { x: "test", y: 55 },
          { x: "hi", y: 20 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQBYENbIgOwGbADmArlOjMLnAL5x5QQhwDkAxhrAHQBWAzswG4AUENa5e8ADbAcAUzSYYAEXLoAXCg4xs+IqXKUcAHmbS5zADSIAHholQZhKwE8NOYiABGsqNQDaALoAfHAAvHCIQhHR0TDOYLIapjKyllEx0QAmqhoI6RkZkujekrwagRb5BVmqvLIwZXB+edWtcNkw6k0ItiwwshKWcK5wAKyj1FY9SajAQyMATAAM1AFVravr0ZNV1EA)

Comment: this would give the error: 
`Type ChartConfiguration<"line", {x: string, y: number}[]> is not assignable to type ChartConfiguration<"bar" | "line" | "scatter" | "bubble" | "pie" | "doughnut" | "polarArea" | "radar", TData, TLabel>["data"]`

in the html for the `lineChartData`

Comment: Although it gives this error within the html page when binding the `lineChartData` or `lineChartOptions` it does work. Thanks for the answer!